# 3rd Party Password Management with Complete Integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, passwords

I use C#, IIS, ASP.NET, SQL Server.

Is there a third-party platform I can easily integrate into my system, to handle password management?

It would have to integrate 100% (no OpenID), so that the users would not notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET actually has some built-in features for login and password management: [the Login Toolbox Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz6e5ezc.aspx). The feature set isn't very large, but it covers all the basics: registration, change password, and recover password.